# Is it possible to split payment between users in stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-processing

I'm working on a uber eat like application, and i want to add a functionality:
When a group of friends order meals, I wants to give user a feature to split the bill between each

Can I divide the bill? like 50% 50% for 2 customers?

Correct me if I'm wrong..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to create two separate [PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) and charge each customer separately. You would divide the bill in two programmatically, and then create a PaymentIntent for each. There is no way to split a single PaymentIntent into more than one charge. You can read more on how to accept payments here:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And if the 2nd payment fail, i need to cancel the first one?

Comment: What you can do is authorize the two payment before capturing them. This effectively places a hold on the two customer's cards. If both authorizations succeed, then you capture both payments. If one fails, then you can simply let the funds release automatically (after seven days) or you can cancel it manually. You can read more on how to do that here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later

Comment: Thank you so much! i'll do that!